# Cannot Await BackgroundWorker CancelAsync

Tags: vb.net, winforms, async-await, backgroundworker

I have a BackgroundWorker in my project that I want to restart in a single method. However, when I use the `CancelAsync()` method and then the `RunWorkerAsync()` method immediately after, the cancel hasn't completed and 2 instances of the BackgroundWorker are started and an InvalidOperationException is thrown. To combat this, I made the method async (it's a Sub method) and awaited the `CancelAsync()` to wait for it to finish. However, this returns an error that the expression doesn't produce a value. Is this due to the calling or the worker's method?

Worker Method:

```
Private Sub GIFworker(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bkwGIF.DoWork
        Dim hum As Integer = e.Argument
        If hum Mod 2 = 1 Then
            While bkwGIF.CancellationPending = False
                pbxRpsHum.Image = ilRPS.Images(0)
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
                pbxRpsHum.Image = ilRPS.Images(1)
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
            End While
        Else
            While bkwGIF.CancellationPending = False
                pbxRpsHum.Image = ilRPS.Images(0)
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
                pbxRpsHum.Image = ilRPS.Images(3)
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
            End While
        End If
    End Sub
```

Calling `CancelAsync()` (hum is an integer):

```
Await bkwGIF.CancelAsync()
bkwGIF.RunWorkerAsync(hum)
```

Comment: BackgroundWorker still passes control to the RunworkerCompleted event. Set the result to a value like 0 for Cancelled, then in your RunWorkerCompleted event check the result and restart the backgroundworker from there.

Comment: You need to do some reading on the `BackgroundWorker` class.  `CancelAsync` is not awaitable. It's part of an older async pattern.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b, that's not the way to do it.  If you detect `CancellationPending` is `True` in the `DoWork` event handler and you do indeed cancel the work, you are supposed to set `e.Cancel` to `True`. You can then check `e.Cancelled` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler and it will also be `True`.

Comment: Oh ok. Wasn't aware of the e.Cancelled part. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you cancel a `BackgroundWorker`:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Raise the DoWork event in a worker thread.
    Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

'This method is executed in a worker thread.
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)

    For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        If worker.CancellationPending Then
            'The user has cancelled the background operation.
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If

        'Raise the ProgressChanged event in the UI thread.
        worker.ReportProgress(i, i & " iterations complete")

        'Perform some time-consuming operation here.
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
    Next i
End Sub

'This method is executed in the UI thread.
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Me.Label1.Text = TryCast(e.UserState, String)
End Sub

'This method is executed in the UI thread.
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled Then
        'The background operation was cancelled.
        Me.Label1.Text = "Operation cancelled"
    Else
        'The background operation completed normally.
        Me.Label1.Text = "Operation complete"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Only cancel the background opertion if there is a background operation in progress.
    If Me.BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
        Me.BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to restart the background work on a cancellation then you would do so in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler when you detect that `e.Cancelled` is `True`.